# Changing window width and height by disassembler

Tags: ida, disassembly, cheat-engine

Well I have IDA and Cheat Engine. What I'm trying to do is change application resolution, actually just a width and height of the window. I know that changing just width and height will not make application work correctly, but it is my first step of understanding disassembler. 
After not a long search I found function CreateWindowEx. Well, looks like I found where application create window,

```
push 1E0h
push 280h
….            ;some code
mov esi, ds:GetSystemMetrics
push 0        ;nIndex
call esi      ;GetSystemMetric
push 1        ;nIndex
move edi,eax
call esi      ;GetSystemMetrics
...           ;somecode
call ds:CreateWindowExA
```

well `push 1E0h` = 480 and `push 280h`=640. Hm, look like I found width and height, so I got adresses of constant, let try to change them. (Actually by searching I find two more places with this constant. But all of them not used for creating window, and since I just try change window hieght and width I'll work with that ones). Run application and cheat Engine.

Hex Value: 280    (1E0)
scan type :Exact Value 
Type: 4bytes

First scan: found 33

look at the list of address non of them even close to the address that we had in IDA. And if I understand correctly it because cheat engine get addresses from memory that is used for running application while Ida analyze the code and find addresses in it. I don't know if I said it correctly or even wrong, any explanation from your side will be good. But the problem is not on it.

Well let add address manually. Ok we got it, and the value on this address is 163944. What? Let look at hexadecimal: 00028068. Hm, I see the 280 on it but where th 68 came from? Let look at height: 122984->0001E068.

So now I got a question why it is so? Where this 68 in the end came from? 
1E0 is not equel of 1E068. Am I wrong? Any suggestions what I missed.

Ok, let go further, let try to change it. Well I tied two variants in hexadecimal: 50068 and 3C068. And without 68, how actually it is suppose to be (in my opinion :) ). None of them is not working, well I think it is probably because application use constant later by pointers (I think, but probably im wrong). So I need to change pointers too.
 Let find what accesses this addresses. Well, now I got a problem, in simple variant to find out what have accesses this addresses you just need to change condition in your aplication let say value=5, you click the button to change value value=3 and cheat engine find what have access to that address. However in my case window was already created, and I don't know how to get this list. So now im kind of stuck in this point. May be I missed something. But any suggestion in what direction move or what i did wrong will help.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple of pointers.

1. The addresses in IDA are based on the base address IDA reads for your executable.  When your program is loaded by the OS, it will reside in a different memory location (most of the time).  So your addresses in IDA will be different than those in memory.  The offset from the base address should be the same all the time.
2. Your hex value may just take up 2 bytes, and I would guess that your architecture is Little Endian.  Thus the 68 may not be related to your actual value, but a different variable.